# how to setup a EmbeddedSolrServer instance?

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I am having trouble getting an `EmbeddedSolrServer` to run. The JavaDoc for `CoreContainer` is sparse to say the least. I've looked at the "MergeIndexesEmbeddedTest" and my code seems like it should work. (This is a Maven project) I have both "Schema.xml" and "solr.xml" in the root of the `src/main/resources` folder. I can able to instantiate ther server, but when I try to add a `SolrInputDocument` to the the server I get:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 'No such core: butterfly'
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:104)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:64)
```

My code that sets up the server is:

```
final File solrConfigXml = new File( "C:/code/butterfly/src/main/resources/solr.xml" );
final String solrHome = "C:/code/butterfly/src/main/resources/";
CoreContainer coreContainer;
try{
    coreContainer = new CoreContainer( solrHome, solrConfigXml );
}catch( Exception e ){
    e.printStackTrace( System.err );
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}
solrServer = new EmbeddedSolrServer( coreContainer, "butterfly" );
```

and my `solr.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="butterfly1">
          <core name="butterfly" instanceDir="." />
    </cores>
</solr>
```

I haven't posted my `Schema.xml` file since it is just a pruned version of the example one with different field names. I am using absolute files path just because it seemed easier to just get started.

Comment: Does the core folder exist?  Are there any messages in the log before the one you've shown?

Answer (score 1):

In your solr.xml snippet, the defaultCoreName is butterfly1. There is no core with name =butterfly1 in your schema.

What version of solr server are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens mostly when [`EmbeddedSolrServer`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.html) is unable to find the core. Usually because the `core.properties` file is missing (have a look at [Solr configuration files](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/solr-configuration-files.html)).

Given that are many things that can go wrong, recently I wrote a Java example that helps to write your own test configuration, load data and run junit tests.

https://github.com/freedev/EmbeddedSolrServer-junit-example